# Convergence of operators and evaluation map for functions with values in a locally convex space

Tags: functional-analysis

Let $E$ be a locally convex Hausdorff topological vector space, and $U$ a domain in $\mathbb{R}^n$. Suppose that we are given a continuous linear map $T: E \to C^{\infty}(U) \otimes E$. (The space $C^{\infty}(U)$ is given its Frechet topology of convergence of functions and their derivatives on compact subsets, and the tensor product is given the projective topology)

Every point $x \in U$ leads to an evaluation map $ev_x:C^\infty(U) \to \mathbb{R}$, and so to every point in $x$ we obtain from $T$ an endomorphism $T_x$ of $E$ by postcomposition.

This means that from some $T$ in the form given above we obtain a set map $U \to \mathcal{L}(E,E)$ (the set of continuous linear endomorphisms of $E$). I would like to know under what topologies on $\mathcal{L}(E,E)$ this map will be continuous.

Given a sequence of points $x_i$ in $U$ converging to $x$, what is the finest topology on $\mathcal{L}(E,E)$ such that $T_{x_i}$ converges to $T_x$ when $x_i$ converges to $x$? Specifically, does the sequence of operators $T_{x_i}$converge in the topology of uniform convergence on bounded subsets?

I know that there is convergence in the topology of pointwise convergence, which I see as follows. Given a vector $v\in E$, its image $T(v) \in C^{\infty}(U) \otimes E$ can be identified with a smooth $E$-valued function $f$ on $U$, which is in particular a continuous function, so that $f(x_i)$ converges to $f(x)$.